# Connecting wireless devices to the bridged network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I've got two advantech EKI-6331AN devices that are working in a bridge mode. Currently there are two PCs conected directly to them at the both ends. Additionally I've got two wireless clients (android phones). I would like to connect them to the same network, one on each side. For the project it is necessary for them to share the same SSID. How can I make it happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "professional" way would be to get two wireless access points and switches and set them up as per the manual.

A more "super user" way would be to take any two wireless routers and disable the routing features, either with custom firmware or just by turning off DHCP and/or WAN and/or NAT where possible in the stock firmware. The plug the PC and wireless bridges into the LAN ports.

Comment: I'm going to try the "super user" way now. I'll let you know if it works